# Where is class weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory?

Tags: jar, weblogic, jndi

when trying to execute my jar file I get an exception:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory 
[Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]
```

I guess this is some kind of missing library on the classpath.
Can anyone tell me which jar-file is missing? I can't find the class weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory anywhere...

Thanks!

P.S.: I already have weblogic 10.0 jar included.

Answer (score 14):

Check your server/lib/ folder to find wliclient.jar.

With Weblogic 12.1.3, you can find it here:
`${INSTALL_DIR}/inventory/wlserver/server/lib/wlclient.jar`

Answer (score 6):

*Step 1:*

Go to `E:\weblogic81\user_projects\domains\mydomain`.    Then type `Setenv` command. As follows

```
E:\weblogic81\user_projects\domains\mydomain>setenv
```

*Step 2:*

`Weblogic.jar` file is needed by your client application.    It may contain in the following path `E:\weblogic81\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar`. so set the classpath for the this folder or copy this weblogic.jar file into your application-folder so that weblogic.jar file is available to your application first.

```
E:\weblogic81\user_projects\domains\mydomain>set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;E:\weblogic81\weblogic81\server\lib;.
```

*Step 3:*

Go to domain folder in command prompt as shown above and set classpath.
To not to disturb other classpaths set classpath as:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;E:\weblogic81\weblogic81\server\lib;.
```

Here (`.`) dot represents set classpath to current directory.

*Step 4:*

After classpath set run command STARTWEBLOGIC as follows:

```
E:\weblogic81\user_projects\domains\mydomain>STARTWEBLOGIC
```

*Step 5:*

Do not login to weblogic server. If you are already login just log out and write the following code in myeclipse or some other IDE.

*Step 6:*

```java
package directory.service;
import java.util.*;
import weblogic.jndi.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.naming.*;
public class GetInitContext {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try{
        weblogic.jndi.Environment env=new weblogic.jndi.Environment();
    weblogic.jndi.Environment environment = new weblogic.jndi.Environment();
        environment.setInitialContextFactory(
          weblogic.jndi.Environment.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        env.setProviderUrl("t3://localhost:7001");
        env.setSecurityPrincipal("agni");
        env.setSecurityCredentials("agnidevam");
        Context context=env.getInitialContext();
        System.out.println("got the initial context for weblogic server---> "+context);
        context.createSubcontext("sone");
        context.bind("agni one",new Integer(10));
        context.createSubcontext("sone/sctwo");
        context.bind("agni two",new Integer(20));
        context.createSubcontext("sone/sctwo/scthree");
        context.bind("agni three",new Integer(30));
        System.out.println("subcontex object created please check in admin server for more details");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("file inputstream exception  ---> "+e);
        }
    }

}
```

*Step 7:*

Execute the above code and login to weblogic and  right click on `myserver>view jndi tree>` you find the bound objects information.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following tag in your build.xml

property name="WLS_HOME" value="${env.WLS_HOME}"

where WLS_HOME=c:\weblogic\wls\wlserver if running on  windows
i kept trying to run a simple hello world program and it kept throwing

*run:

```
 [echo] Executing client class  
 [java] javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]*
```

once i changed the above mentioned tag it in the build.xml it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

it looks you are doing a JNDI lookup outside of WLS.

You need to use wlfulclient.jar or if your machine has a WLS installation then add to your classpath project: WL_HOME/server/lib/weblogic.jar

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and it's fixed now :)

The fix is, to go to WebLogic server and navigate to /Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/ and execute the below command.

Command: java -jar wljarbuilder.jar -profile wlfullclient5

The above command creates a jar file with all the jar's inside WebLogic server /lib folder and place it in your client java code build path Eclipse and craetes runnable JAR file and place this wlfullclient5.jar file in server/lib folder as well.

Hope this helps! Kindly let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Adding wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar is enough. I test it.

Answer (score 0):

It is packaged inside of the weblogic.jar under your server/lib.

Answer (score 0):

in version 12c it is located in weblogic-classes.jar in your lib directory:

C:\wls1213\wlserver\server\lib

Answer (score 0):

For `WLS 12.2`, where WL_HOME is The BEA home directory of your WebLogic installation

(as defualt `WL_HOME` is `Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver`)

```
%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wlclient.jar
%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wls-api.jar 
%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wls-api-part.jar 
%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wlthint3client.jar
```

all these libs contains the: `jar: weblogic\jndi\WLInitialContextFactory.class`

see WLS doc.: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wlprg/overview.html#GUID-FC14CC53-DE49-456F-B54C-D73CC6DBF818

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the issue stated here and I've managed to solved by fixing `WL_HOME` enviroment variable.

In my case the `wlserver_10.3` folder was moved to another drive (From `D` to `E`) and the guy who did the disk "migration" forgot to change the WL_HOME value at `PATH\TO\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\common\bin`

By fixing the `wlserver_10.3` path I was able to deploy `JAR's` at WebLogic